# Output a custom message during a dpkg package installation

Tags: installation, package, dpkg

I am trying to install create a simple `.deb` `dpkg` package.

I have seen multiple packages where, during installation, they output custom messages like `Reboot after installation!` or `Clearing caches` or (in the case of iOS) `Thanks to [developer]!`.

I can't seem to find any way to replicate this myself during installation of my package.

How do I output a custom message to the terminal while `dpkg` is installing my package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by providing a postinst script to the package.

See section [7.6 What is a Debian preinst, postinst, prerm, and postrm script?](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-maintscripts)